# real media player video and audio files. (.rm and .ram) used in html code not working in current browser

Tags: html, audio, video, html4

I have a code containing real media player video and audio files. (.rm and .ram). They are not working in browsers. Can you please suggest a solution. The code contains an embed tag which has a .rpm file in src. The .rpm file contains path to a .smi file which contains the .rm video and audio files to be played on clicking a button in browser. But this is not working as it should. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the RealMedia files to a modern format, such as MP3 for audio files, or MPEG4 for video files.

RealMedia has been effectively obsolete for the last five to ten years (depending on how you define "obsolete"), and is no longer playable in any modern web browser.