# Equivalent tag of <audio controls> to play rm files

Tags: html

The mp3 player will be automatically embedded in the html when we add `<audio controls>` tag

example, `<audio controls><source src="sample.mp3" /></audio>`

It works fine for mp3 files But this doesn't work for rm files since the tag doesn't support rm files i.e real media player files

Do we have any equivalent tag to play rm files?

Thanks.

Comment: The world has given up on RM files a long time ago. It's probably easier if you just convert them to something else rather than doing hacky things to make them work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [real media player video and audio files. (.rm and .ram) used in html code not working in current browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360117/real-media-player-video-and-audio-files-rm-and-ram-used-in-html-code-not-wo)

Comment: Some of them still uses rm files. Conversion is not the sol/ution. Deprecated file types should also be supported. any way to play them

Comment: Those files are not deprecated, they're obsolete. Deprecated means they're in the last stages of support. Today support has been completely dropped.

Comment: I agree support has been stopped.However is it possible to play the files in any audio player in web?

Comment: It probably is only possible by using a 3rd party plugin or writing a plugin in e.g. flash or a Java applet (but those are blocked by default on browsers so users will need to unblock them)

Comment: Can u suggest any 3rd party plugin which plays this file?

Comment: Found one but not in active dev - http://jquery.malsup.com/media/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 can only play standard formats. Initially it was planned to use ogg vorbis and ogg theora for audio and video, then google came up with VP8 (WebM) as free high quality codec. Later browsers added mp3 (audio) and mp4 (video) for practical reasons, even when they are legally complicated (patent issues).
Support for real media is not implemented and never was a design goal.

But you can of course embed real media like people did before HTML5 with object/embed tags, see for example [this howto](http://kingsolutions.org.uk/wordpress/web_design-index/streaming-multimedia-video-and-audio/embedding-realmedia-files-using-html/). Note that this requires your users to install the real media plugin (NPAPI / ActiveX), but there is no other way.

The best way would be to convert your media if you have any possibility to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The only other way I can think apart from downloading or converting is to use Flash.  I have never programmed Flash myself but I think there will be a  way to do it.  I would be very surprised if it is not possible.

Most computers have a plugin for Flash already since a lot of content uses Flash and although this makes it inconvenient I think this will the best option for an already existing plugin.  Of course you could create your own or use another but I don't recommend that partly because of users trust or may not know how to add a plugin.

As I said above it is preferable to convert to a supported format. As the other answer suggests.